# How to find all keys within a dictionary which contains only ALL values from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter, key

i'am new in python. I Am currently working on a script that filters job applicants by which programing languages they use. I've a dictionary containing each candidate (keys) and her language (value). I want to find ONLY the keys within a dictionary whose values contains ALL items contained in a list. For example:

```
list1 = ['php', 'net']
dict  = {
    'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python'], 
    'john': ['php', 'c++'], 
    'ian' : ['php','python']}
```

Using this example what i want to get would be only the key 'lara', which is the only one containing all the values listed within list1. I've searched like mad for a solution to this problem but so far i've found nothing around and neither could make it work for myself.

Any help will be welcome

Comment: You could go by using sets and function `issubset`

Comment: Well - what problem has the solution you derived? And where is it? why do you shadow the built in dict by using it as variable name?

Comment: closing braket for dict is missing ! please be careful to share complete portion of code!

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension and `all`

```
list1 = ['php', 'net']
d = {'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python'], 'john': ['php', 'c++'], 'ian': ['php','python']}
print([k for k,v in d.items() if all(i in v for i in list1)])
```

**Output:**

```
['lara']
```

*Expanded version.*

```
res = []
for k,v in d.items():
    if all(i in v for i in list1):
        res.append(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to filter the elements in the dictionary (renamed `dict` to `dikt` below to avoid clashing with the `dict` class). The [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function returns `True` if all elements of the iterable are `True`.

```
list1 = ['php', 'net']
dikt = {'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python'], 'john': ['php', 'c++'], 'ian': ['php','python']}

# Matching keys as a list:

[k for k,v in dikt.items() if all(x in v for x in list1)]
# ['lara']

# Matching entries returned as a dict:

{k:v for k,v in dikt.items() if all(x in v for x in list1)}
# {'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python']}
```

Comment: This completely solve my problem ¡¡¡ thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `set.isubset` method to find if the given set is subset of the lists

```
list1=['php', 'net']
dict1={'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python'], 'john': ['php', 'c++'], 'ian': ['php','python']}
set1=set(list1)
{k:v for k,v in dict1.items() if set1.issubset(v)}
# {'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets instead of lists.

```
set1 = {'php', 'net'}
dict1 = {'lara': ['net', 'php', 'python'], 'john': ['php', 'c++'], 'ian': ['php','python']}
{k: v for k,v in dict1.items() if set1.issubset(v)}
```